# asp 4.5 role based authorization not loading any other page after opening admin folder's page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, role

I have created an asp.net 4.5 web form application and implemented role based authentication and authorization in it by following [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Role-based-Authorization-and-Authentication-in-ASPNet.aspx) article. Although I have not used `<asp:Menu/>` control, so I skipped creating the web.sitemap file. I used a `bootstrap navigational bar` in my `site.master` page.

I have three roles in my application including an `Admin` role. I have a separate page for admin, so I moved that `web form` file in the `Admin` folder. Here is a screenshot of my solution: [image: Project Solution]

**My other two roles, Receptionist and Physician works fine after login. They can navigate the pages they are allowed to. When an admin logs in and goes to the `AddPhysician.aspx` page, the `url` looks like this: `http://localhost:58246/Admin/AddPhysician.aspx` and loads fine except the `nav bar`(the logo doesn't load)[image].

Now when I click any other page from `navigational bar`(`Home page` for example), the `url` looks like this: `http://localhost:58246/Admin/Home.aspx`. And this gives me an `/`error like this: [image: error]
Why it is searching `Home.aspx` page in `Admin` folder rather than main directory?**

Here is my root `web.config` file:

```
    <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Here is the content `web.config` file inside `Admin` folder.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="Administrator"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
     </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Please do tell me if anyone need additional material to understand the problem.

**Edit**
I'm adding the contents `AddPhysician.aspx` file here:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddPhysician.aspx.cs" Inherits="PresentationLayer.Admin.AddPhysician" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: inherit;
            margin-top:5%; /*This*/
        }

        table {
            width:50%;
        }

            table.center {
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: 3px solid #bdc3c7;
                border-width: thick;
                border-collapse: separate;
                border-spacing: 1.4em;
                /*background: rgba(211,76,190,0.88);*/
                margin-bottom:5%; /*This*/
                background-image: url(/content/images/physician_tools.jpg);
            }

        .pageTitle {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            font-style: oblique;
            text-align: center;
            color:#2c3e50;
            font-weight:700;
        }
        .formLabels{
            color: #3498db;

        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <%--<form  method="post" runat="server">--%>
        <table class="center">
             <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label CssClass="label label-info" ID="lblPatientID" Text="User ID" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-lg" Enabled="false" ForeColor="#00CC99"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="lblFristN" Text="First Name" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFristN" runat="server" Class="form-control input-sm"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldValidatorFName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFristN" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please Enter First Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExpressionValidatorFName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFristN" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Only Lower and Upper case alphabets are allowed in First Name" ValidationExpression="[a-z,A-Z]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="lblLastN"  Text="Last Name" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Class="form-control input-sm" ID="txtLastN" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldValidatorLastN" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastN" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Enter the Last Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExpressionValidatorLastN" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastN" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Only Lower and Upper case alphabets are allowed in Last Name" ValidationExpression="[a-z,A-Z]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text="Gender" AssociatedControlID="rblGender"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGender" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="M" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="F" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Please select a gender" ControlToValidate="rblGender" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="labelDepartment" Text="Department" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control input-sm" ID="DropDownLDepartment" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldValidatorDeparment" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="DropDownLDepartment" InitialValue="Select a Plan" ErrorMessage="Please select an Insurence Plan" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="LabelEduQ"  Text="Educational Qualification" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Class="form-control input-sm" ID="TextBoxEduQ" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorEduQ" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEduQ" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Educational Qualification"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExpressionValidatorEduQ" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEduQ" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Only Lower and Upper case alphabets and '.'`s and space's are allowed in Educational Qualification" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\s\.]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="LabelExp"  Text="Years of Experience" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Class="form-control input-sm" ID="TextBoxExp" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorExp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxExp" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Years of experience"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExpressionValidatorExp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxExp" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Only a one or two digit integer is allowed in Years of Experience" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{1,2}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="LabelState" Text="State" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control input-sm" ID="DropDownLState" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldValidatorState" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="DropDownLState" InitialValue="Select a State" ErrorMessage="Please select a state" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <asp:Label class="label label-info" ID="LabelIns" Text="Insurence Plan" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control input-sm" ID="DropDownLPlns" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorIns" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="DropDownLPlns" InitialValue="Select a Plan" ErrorMessage="Please select an Insurence Plan" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ID="buttonRegister" Text="Register" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ID="buttonReset" Text="Reset" runat="server" OnClientClick="" OnClick="btnReset_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValSumRegister" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <%--</form>--%>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Seems to be paths issue. Can you put contents of `AddPhysicians.aspx` from admin folder?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether it is the appropriate solution but here it is. I just moved the `AddPhysician.aspx` file to main directory and changed its `inherits` directory to `PresentationLayer.AddPhysician`(moved the directory one time backward). Then I added another `location` path for `AddPhysician` in main `web.config` file and set the `allowed role` to `Administrator` and deleted the `Admin` folder. Now it works just fine.

I think the problem was`AddPhysician.aspx` file not being able to acquire the `site.master` page properly.